# Date formats don't match and pandas uses wrong century

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm fairly new to python, and I'm having a hard time cleaning up some data.  I have two data sets that I intend to concatenate and then do a little analysis on.  The date column is in a different format, and I'm struggling to deal with this.  The issue is that in the second data set, the year is only 2 digits, and when I use `pd.to_datetime` it sometimes guesses the wrong century.  What's the best way to make these two formats match up?  I'd like to do some time series stuff with this.  There is no overlap as the earliest date in this data set is 1939.

both are read in with Dtype Object.

Example Data

```
import pandas as pd 

data1 = {'col1': ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'], 'col2': ['1939, May', '1940, June', '2015, March'],}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['col1', 'col2'])
df1
    col1    col2
0   row1    1939, May
1   row2    1940, June
2   row3    2015, March

data2 = {'col1': ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'], 'col2': ['Dec-1939', 'Apr-1980', 'Aug-2011'],}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['col1', 'col2'])
df2

col1    col2
0   row1    Dec-1960
1   row2    Apr-1980
2   row3    Aug-2011
```

This works well on df1 `pd.to_datetime(df['col2'], format='%Y, %B', errors='coerce')`, but when i change `format='%b-%y'` for df2, it will change 1939 to 2039.  I figured it is best to create a matching format before concatenating the two data frames..

Comment: The rule is that two digits dates run from 1970 to 2069.  You'll have to fix your data before you import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried leaving out `format`? Pandas can usually just autodetect.

**df1:**

```py
df1.col2 = pd.to_datetime(df1.col2)

#    col1       col2
# 0  row1 1939-05-01
# 1  row2 1940-06-01
# 2  row3 2015-03-01
```

**df2:**

```py
df2.col2 = pd.to_datetime(df2.col2)

#    col1       col2
# 0  row1 1939-12-01
# 1  row2 1980-04-01
# 2  row3 2011-08-01
```

Comment: This gives me the 2062 dates. Maybe I need to update something?

Comment: I should mention I tried this on my actual dataset which has about 6k rows.

Comment: @pkpto39 Does it work properly with the toy examples? Or it breaks even with the simplified toy examples? What's your `pd.__version__`?

Answer (score 0):

In your case should be 'Y'

```
pd.to_datetime(df2['col2'], format='%b-%Y', errors='coerce')
Out[9]: 
0   1939-12-01
1   1980-04-01
2   2011-08-01
Name: col2, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```